# Estimated App Store Size on Xcode 6 is showing huge size (Unity iOS Export)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode6

I have been making builds using Xcode 5.x so far. My app size (Estimated app store size) was around 55MB. Just after updating to Xcode 6.0.1. The same app is now showing 145MB. I read in few places that it is showing download app size. But this is just a speculation.

here is a link for people facing same issue 
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/estimated-app-size-increased-considerably-on-newest-unity.269245/

This is a Unity game. Is this only  related to Unity's exported projects or this is a new behaviour of Xcode's "Estimated app store size"?

Comment: i do have the same issue from 120MB to 306MB

Comment: I have updated one application which was 65MB earlier. Now its showing 156MB. Once it gets approved then i'll post the final result here. That would clarify everything.

Comment: that would be nice, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i got my game approved from Apple and the size is 56MB (same as the build made with Xcode 5.X). So i am now sure that Xcode 6 shows downloaded size of the app or as it appears from my experience.

So don't worry :) your app is going to be what it should be.

Comment: I was confused as well at first.  If you export it as an ad hoc (appname.ipa), you can see that the file size is what it used to show in the previous version of XCode.  I believe this is a bug in XCode 6.  It's showing the uncompressed, in-memory size of the app on the device.  They either need to rename it in the Organizer as such or fix it.